# which SEO for page url extension is better

Tags: url, seo

i'm on a new website and wondering for a while which is better of these suggesions for a url?

`http://medical-eg.com/dr/name` OR
`http://medical-eg.com/dr.name`

i see the second one is simpler and more grammatical.

but i don't want it to be on the favor of SEO.

thanks all....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search engine optimization. Try visiting [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is far better then the second one.
There are few benefits of it

First : Two keywords get target dr and name
along with that third keyword dr name will also get targeted.

Second : It will give an feel of categorised page to google and pages which are well categorised rank high

and there are many other benefits..

Comment: when u say there are many other benefits, either explain or dont write that.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better, it is currently being used by latest Microsoft's MVC 3 and MVC 4 framework as well. Apart from that it helps the crawler to get information about the page much easier as compared to used dr.name like structure.

Comment: thnx alot for this reply

Answer (score 1):

The 1st is the best of the two.
I would go for a different approach

`http://medical-eg.com/dr-name-surname`

also adding geo location to the url could boost SEO

`http://medical-eg.com/geo-location/dr-name-surname`